# How to write Api contract for @RequestPart for multi-part data

Tags: spring, postman, swagger, openapi, multipart

I am trying to add open api to my project so it can expose the swagger to my baseURL.
This is my request mapping

```
  @PostMapping(path = "/{referenceId}")
  public Mono<DocumentUploadResponse> upload(

          @PathVariable(value = "referenceId") String referenceId,
          @RequestPart(value = "documents") List<FilePart> document,
          @RequestPart(value = "documentsMetaData") DocumentMetaDataApplicationRequest documentMetaDataApplicationRequest) {

    return documentStorageService.upload(referenceId, document, documentMetaDataApplicationRequest);

  }
```

This is my APIContract

```
parameters = {
                @Parameter(
                        in = ParameterIn.PATH,
                        name = "referenceId",
                        description = "unique Id provided by consumer application, against which documents are stored for respective bookings"),
                @Parameter(
                        in = ***? what to write here for my @RequestPart?***
                        name = "documents",
                        description = "The number of the booking."),
                @Parameter(
                        in = **? what to write here for my @RequestPart?**
                        name = "documentsMetaData",
                        description = "The number of the booking.")
        })
```

What should I use here -in = ParameterIn.PATH for @RequestPart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requestBody = @RequestBody(
            content = @Content(
                    schema = @Schema(
                        implementation = DocumentUploadRequest.class,
                            description = "DocumentUploadRequest"
                    ), mediaType = "multipart/form-data"

            ),
            required = true

    )
```

Make a custom class for your